# Шифр Виженера

Tags: .net, шифрование, c#

Здравствуйте, есть проблема с реализацией шифра Виженера. Не получается доступаться к элементам таблицы и записать в стринговый литерал.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_shifr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Schifrovanie();
    }

    private void Schifrovanie()
    {
        string key = txbx_key.ToString();
        string x = "";
        string alf = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
        string tmp;
        string rez = "";
        int p = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < key.Length; k++)
        {
            p = alf.IndexOf(key.Substring(k, 1));
            for (int j = 0; j < alf.Length; j++)
            {
             //Составление таблицы Виженера
                x = alf.Substring((j + p) % alf.Length, 1);
            //шифрование открытого текста
                //tmp = alf.Substring(txbx_openText.Text.Substring(j, 1)% txbx_key.Text.Length);
                rez += tmp;
            }
        }                      
    }
}
```

Comment: Не до конца понятно, что именно не получается. Вы хотите часть строки вставить в другую строку по некому правилу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учебный, но вполне рабочий пример.

```
/* Кодирование с помощью таблиц Вижинера,
получает символ таблицы на пересечении элементов */
unsigned char GetChar( int yp, int xp )
{
   long  nRes = (((yp - xp) < 0) ? ((yp - xp) + 256) : (yp - xp));
   return (unsigned char)nRes;
}

/* кодирует строку:
out_str - массив выходной строки,
in_str - массив входной строки,
password - массив символов с паролем */
void CodeStr( char *out_str, char *in_str, char *password )
{
   unsigned char pass_index, pass_len, str_len, x;
   pass_len = strlen( password );
   str_len = strlen( in_str );
   for( pass_index=x=0; x<str_len; x++ )
   {
      out_str[x] = GetChar( in_str[x], password[ pass_index ] );
      pass_index++;
      if ( pass_index >= pass_len ) pass_index = 0;
   }
   out_str[x] = '\0';
}

/* декодирует строку */
void DecodeStr( char *out_str, char *in_str, int str_len, char *password )
{
   unsigned char pass_index, pass_len;
   int k, x;
   pass_len = strlen( password );

   for( pass_index=k=0; k<str_len; k++ )
   {
      for( x=0; x<=255; x++ )
         if ( GetChar( x,password[ pass_index ] ) == in_str[k] ) break;

      out_str[k] = GetChar( x,0 );
      pass_index++;
      if ( pass_index>=pass_len ) pass_index=0;
   }
   out_str[k] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю C#, но в целом алгоритм понятен.

На самом деле результатом вложенных циклов д.б. массив из k циклически переставленных строк alf. (Вектор указателей на строки? На Си , я это назвал бы так.)

Далее посимвольно просматриваете шифруемый текст и делаете замену. i-ый символ меняете (аналогично тому, как вычисляли p) на символ из строки, с индексом `i%k` (скажем, `tab[i%k]`), где k это длина ключа.

У Вас в функции `Schifrovanie()` написано (не до конца, я бы назвал это наброском) только создание таблицы Вижинера (думаю это называется так), а само шифрование вообще опущено. Часть в комментарии `//tmp = alf.Substring(txbx\_openText.Text.Substring(j, 1)% txbx_key.Text.Length);` очевидно не по месту.

Видимо у Вас во внутреннем цикле надо написать `res += x;` Перед внутренним циклом res = "";
А после внутреннего цикла `tab[k] = res`. Как сделать tab[] размером key.Length элементов на C# не знаю .

Comment: В этой строчке //tmp = alf.Substring(txbx_openText.Text.Substring(j, 1)% txbx_key.Text.Length); я пытался заменить открытый текст на шифрованный, но возникла ошибка. В переменную p попадают символы таблицы. У меня не получается сделать само шифрование открытого текста, т.е. заменить символы открытого(openText) текста с помощью ключа(переменная key) на шифрованный текст.

Comment: Ну я же написал. В той части (2 вложенных цикла), что у Вас написана строится **только** таблица для шифрования.  
Само шифрование должно быть написано в цикле **после** этих 2-х циклов.  
  
Кстати, **любые** символы входного текста (и ключа) надо как-то отображать на alf. У Вас перечислены только заглавные русские. А что делать с другими (цифры, латынь ...) ?

Comment: Вот, прямо сейчас пришел в голову другой алгоритм. Ключ (длиной К) задает смещения для символов шифруемого текста ( в арифметике для одного байта).

Просто к каждому входящему символу прибавляем соответствующий символ ключа (по модулю). Когда ключ заканчивается возвращаемся к его началу. 

А при дешифровке вычитаем.  


Не знаю, конечно, с точки зрения криптоанализа это то же самое, что шифр Вижинера ?